# Load the JQuery Datatables with the data from the servlet via Ajax

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, servlets, datatables

I have looked for similar posts here, but i couldn't find post that matches my requirements. I am trying to display the **jquery datatables**. On the UI, i get to date parameters and make a ajax call to the servlet. The servlet will process and return the json data. Once i get the data i want to show the results in the datatables. But my code is not working. I am new to Datatables. Here's my code :

```
function fetchLogs(){
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "LogsServlet",
    data: 'FromDate='+from+'&'+'ToDate='+to,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data){
        /*$('#logs').dataTable({
            "aaData": data,
            "aoColumns": [{ "mDataProp": "Executed_AT" }, { "mDataProp": "User_Name"}]
        });*/
        $('#logs').dataTable( {
            "bProcessing": true,
            "sAjaxSource": data
        } );

    }

});

}
```

**The json data that the servlet returns:**

```
[{"user_id":"rams.orvz@xyz.com","executed_at":"Jul 8, 2013 7:22:59 PM"}]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got the solution. Here's the code that solved it:

```
 function fetchLogs(){
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "LogsServlet",
    data: 'FromDate='+from+'&'+'ToDate='+to,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: AjaxFetchDataSucceeded,
    error: AjaxFetchDataFailed

});

}

function AjaxFetchDataSucceeded(result) {
    if (result != "[]") {
        //var dataTab = $.parseJSON(result);
        $('#logs').dataTable({
            "bProcessing": true,
            "aaData": result,
            //important  -- headers of the json
            "aoColumns": [{ "mDataProp": "user_id" }, { "mDataProp": "executed_at" }],
            "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
            "aaSorting": [[0, "asc"]],
            "bJQueryUI": true

        });
    }
}

function AjaxFetchDataFailed(result) {
    alert(result.status + ' ' + result.statusText);
}
```

However the displayed data tables are totally awkward in terms of appearance.